I am facing issue with git pull and git fetch
When I take a pull from develop branch or any other branch. It stucked at some point and does not processed further.It works fine when I push my code.(https://i.sstatic.net/4aVHhe9L.png)
I did tried with several ways -

Turn off window defender wirewall.
traceout host/IP it shows requested time out at some hop.
checked ping it show 100% loss.
tried with different network.
added new SSH key and deleted all old keys.
Reinstalled git


if pulling from a branch gets stuck try these steps:

Use HTTPS Instead of SSH: Switch the remote URL to HTTPS if SSH is causing issues:

git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/repo.git


Check Network Proxy: Ensure no proxy settings are interfering:

git config --global --unset http.proxy
git config --global --unset https.proxy


Increase Git Timeout:

git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
git config --global http.lowSpeedLimit 0
git config --global http.lowSpeedTime 99999


test with a VPN: If there's a network restriction, try a VPN to bypass it.

Check Repository Health: Pull directly from GitHub using:


git fetch --verbose


Try to set git configuration to handle large files or shallow clone to reduce data transfer:
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
git config --global core.compression 0

or
git pull --depth 1

Thx
